# Im having trouble targeting the 'title' attribute using HideSeek

Tags: jquery, html, search

So I created a gallery with a search bar but I cant seem to target the title attributes of the images so i can search in image that way. IE, to target the first image I want to type into the search bar "I love hay bales." to show the first image. Everytime i type that, it makes all the images disappear. 
this is my code so far:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('#search').hideseek({
  attribute: 'title',
  hidden_mode: false,
  highlight: true 
 });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Photo Gallery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="magnific-popup/magnific-popup.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

</head>
<body>

    <input id="search" name="search" type="text" placeholder="Search(16pt)" data-list=".container">

    <div class="container">
        <a href="photos/01.jpg"><img src="photos/thumbnails/01.jpg" alt="Hay bales" title="I love hay bales. Took this snap on a drive through the countryside past some straw fields."></a>

        <a href="photos/02.jpg"><img src="photos/thumbnails/02.jpg" alt="Lake" title="The lake was so calm today. We had a great view of the snow on the mountains from here."></a>

        <a href="photos/03.jpg"><img src="photos/thumbnails/03.jpg" alt="Canyon" title="I hiked to the top of the mountain and got this picture of the canyon and trees below."></a>

        <a href="photos/04.jpg"><img src="photos/thumbnails/04.jpg" alt="Iceberg" title="It was amazing to see an iceberg up close, it was so cold but didn’t snow today."></a>

        <a href="photos/05.jpg"><img src="photos/thumbnails/05.jpg" alt="Desert" title="The red cliffs were beautiful. It was really hot in the desert but we did a lot of walking through the canyons."></a>

        <a href="photos/06.jpg"><img src="photos/thumbnails/06.jpg" alt="Fall" title="Fall is coming, I love when the leaves on the trees start to change color."></a>

        <a href="photos/07.jpg"><img src="photos/thumbnails/07.jpg" alt="Plantation" title="I drove past this plantation yesterday, everything is so green!"></a>

        <a href="photos/08.jpg"><img src="photos/thumbnails/08.jpg" alt="Dunes" title="My summer vacation to the Oregon Coast. I love the sandy dunes!"></a>

        <a href="photos/09.jpg"><img src="photos/thumbnails/09.jpg" alt="Countryside Lane" title="We enjoyed a quiet stroll down this countryside lane."></a>

        <a href="photos/10.jpg"><img src="photos/thumbnails/10.jpg" alt="Sunset" title="Sunset at the coast! The sky turned a lovely shade of orange."></a>

        <a href="photos/11.jpg"><img src="photos/thumbnails/11.jpg" alt="Cave" title="I did a tour of a cave today and the view of the landscape below was breathtaking."></a>

        <a href="photos/12.jpg"><img src="photos/thumbnails/12.jpg" alt="Bluebells" title="I walked through this meadow of bluebells and got a good view of the snow on the mountain before the fog came in."></a>

    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="magnific-popup/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.hideseek.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/search.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nevermind! I got it to work. I had to change data-list=".container" to data-list="a".

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve same functionality with jQuery only,  no need to use additional plugins like hide seek. Please refer below code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#search").keyup(function() {
    var filter = $(this).val();
    $(".images").each(function() {
      !$(this).attr("title").includes(filter) ? $(this).hide() : $(this).show();
      if (filter == "") {
        $(this).show();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Photo Gallery</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="magnific-popup/magnific-popup.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

</head>

<body>

  <input id="search" name="search" type="text" placeholder="Search(16pt)" data-list=".container">

  <div class="container">
    <a href="photos/01.jpg"><img class="images" src="photos/thumbnails/01.jpg" alt="Hay bales" title="I love hay bales. Took this snap on a drive through the countryside past some straw fields."></a>

    <a href="photos/02.jpg"><img class="images" src="photos/thumbnails/02.jpg" alt="Lake" title="The lake was so calm today. We had a great view of the snow on the mountains from here."></a>

    <a href="photos/03.jpg"><img class="images" src="photos/thumbnails/03.jpg" alt="Canyon" title="I hiked to the top of the mountain and got this picture of the canyon and trees below."></a>

    <a href="photos/04.jpg"><img class="images" src="photos/thumbnails/04.jpg" alt="Iceberg" title="It was amazing to see an iceberg up close, it was so cold but didn’t snow today."></a>

    <a href="photos/05.jpg"><img class="images" src="photos/thumbnails/05.jpg" alt="Desert" title="The red cliffs were beautiful. It was really hot in the desert but we did a lot of walking through the canyons."></a>

    <a href="photos/06.jpg"><img class="images" src="photos/thumbnails/06.jpg" alt="Fall" title="Fall is coming, I love when the leaves on the trees start to change color."></a>

    <a href="photos/07.jpg"><img class="images" src="photos/thumbnails/07.jpg" alt="Plantation" title="I drove past this plantation yesterday, everything is so green!"></a>

    <a href="photos/08.jpg"><img class="images" src="photos/thumbnails/08.jpg" alt="Dunes" title="My summer vacation to the Oregon Coast. I love the sandy dunes!"></a>

    <a href="photos/09.jpg"><img class="images" src="photos/thumbnails/09.jpg" alt="Countryside Lane" title="We enjoyed a quiet stroll down this countryside lane."></a>

    <a href="photos/10.jpg"><img class="images" src="photos/thumbnails/10.jpg" alt="Sunset" title="Sunset at the coast! The sky turned a lovely shade of orange."></a>

    <a href="photos/11.jpg"><img class="images" src="photos/thumbnails/11.jpg" alt="Cave" title="I did a tour of a cave today and the view of the landscape below was breathtaking."></a>

    <a href="photos/12.jpg"><img class="images" src="photos/thumbnails/12.jpg" alt="Bluebells" title="I walked through this meadow of bluebells and got a good view of the snow on the mountain before the fog came in."></a>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Nice! It's just that the project was asking to use plugins so that's why I was trying to use hideseek. Your response was helpful though!